# Clojure: map over variable length vectors

Tags: clojure

```
(map +  [1 2] 
        [100]
        [1 2 3] 
        [1 2 3 4] )
```

yields (103)

What do I need to make these yield (103 6 6 4)?

Answer (score 2):

Map stops processing as soon as any of the collection arguments are exhausted. Since `[100]` only contains a single element, `map` only processes the first element of each of the collections passed in your example.

If you want to use `map` then you would need to 0 pad the collections so that they have equal size, e.g.:

```
(map +  [1 2 0 0] 
        [100 0 0 0]
        [1 2 3 0] 
        [1 2 3 4])
=> (103 6 6 4)
```

Comment: Are you suggesting, if I have a sequence of vectors of variable size, I have to reprocess it? First to find the largest vector length, then to pad to that length?